# Issue while using SHAP with SwinTransformer

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use SHAP to explain the prediction of fine-tuned Swin-Transformer.

The code is the following:

```
img = plt.imread(path)x_test = image_processor(images=[img], return_tensors="pt")['pixel_values']
```

```
def predict(input_data):
    input_tensor = torch.tensor(input_data).float().to('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(input_tensor)
        probabilities = torch.softmax(output.logits, dim=1).cpu().numpy()
    return probabilities

# Create an example input tensor
input_tensor = torch.zeros([1, 3, 256, 256]).to('cuda')

# Convert the input tensor to a NumPy array
input_array = input_tensor.detach().cpu().numpy()
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(predict, input_array)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(input_array)
```

```
And it gives me this error:
```

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[351], line 1
----> 1 shap_values = explainer.shap_values(input_array)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/shap/explainers/_kernel.py:160, in Kernel.shap_values(self, X, **kwargs)
    158     X = X.tolil()
    159 assert x_type.endswith(arr_type) or sp.sparse.isspmatrix_lil(X), "Unknown instance type: " + x_type
--> 160 assert len(X.shape) == 1 or len(X.shape) == 2, "Instance must have 1 or 2 dimensions!"
    162 # single instance
    163 if len(X.shape) == 1:

AssertionError: Instance must have 1 or 2 dimensions!
```

I've tried different things before, but I keep getting errors related to the input, such as the order of the axis that is wrong, or errors like:

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 484, 3), |u1
```

I'm very new to transformers and pytorch, I'm sorry if it's a dumb question.

I've tried many manipulations of the image array, from np.array to tensor and vice versa. I've also tried to modify the axis order but none of that worked. I'm clearly missing something stupid.